# sending email to smtp server in docker

Tags: email, docker, smtp

I have just installed a docker image of inbucket (http://www.inbucket.org/). It is working ok and I can see in the docker command prompt that smtp is listening on `TCP4 0.0.0.0.10025` and pop3 listening on `TCP4 0.0.0.0.10110`.
I can also access the web interface for the application on `localhost:9000` so everything seems to be working ok.
I haven't used docker before so I'm unsure what email address I need to send it to so the docker smtp server will pick it up. I have tried addressed such as `anyone@inbucket.com`, `anyone@inbucket.local`, `anyone@inbucket.org` but I keep getting invalid address returned messages.

How should docker mailboxes work?

Comment: are you able to ping `www.inbucket.org` ?

Comment: I think you're confusing mail addresses with the server address. It seems like Inbucket doesn't care what the email addresses are. So you just need to use an IP that will resolve to the Docker container (or set up DNS) and make sure your port mapping is set up correctly.